# Using my custom iterator with STL algorithms

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, stl-algorithm

I'm trying to create my own iterator, and I've got it working as expected with the std::generate algorithm. However, when I try std::max_element of std::find, I get some cryptic errors.

Here is the interface for my iterator:

```
template <typename GridT,
          typename GridPtr,
          typename GridRef,
          template <typename> class ShapeT>
class GridIterator
{
public:
    typedef GridIterator<GridT, GridPtr, GridRef, ShapeT> Iterator;

    // Iterator traits - typedefs and types required to be STL compliant
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t           difference_type;
    typedef typename GridT::Element  value_type;
    typedef typename GridT::Element* pointer;
    typedef typename GridT::Element& reference;
    typedef size_t                      size_type;
    std::forward_iterator_tag          iterator_category;


    GridIterator(GridT& grid,
                 ShapeT<typename GridT::Resolution> shape,
                 Index iterStartIndex);

    ~GridIterator();

    Iterator& operator++();
    Iterator  operator++(int);

    typename GridT::Element& operator*();
    typename GridT::Element* operator->();

    bool operator!=(const GridIterator& rhs) const;
    bool operator==(const GridIterator& rhs) const;
    ....
```

}

Using std::find, I get this error:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63:0,
> from ./grid/Map_Grid.h:11,
> from main.cpp:4: /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘_IIter
> std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter =
> Map::GridIterator<Map::Grid<double, int>, Map::Grid<double, int>*,
> Map::Grid<double, int>&, Map::Rectangle>, _Tp = int]’:
> main.cpp:103:50:   instantiated from here
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4404:45: error: no matching
> function for call to
> ‘__iterator_category(Map::GridIterator<Map::Grid<double, int>,
> Map::Grid<double, int>*, Map::Grid<double, int>&, Map::Rectangle>&)’
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4404:45: note: candidate is:
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:202:5: note:
> template typename std::iterator_traits::iterator_category
> std::__iterator_category(const _Iter&)

With std::max_element :

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/char_traits.h:41:0,
> from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:41,
> from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:40,
> from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40,
> from ./grid/Map_GridIterator.h:7,
> from ./grid/Map_Grid.h:8,
> from main.cpp:4: /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h: In function ‘const _Tp&
> std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with _Tp =
> Map::GridIterator<Map::Grid<double, int>, Map::Grid<double, int>*,
> Map::Grid<double, int>&, Map::Rectangle>]’: main.cpp:102:60:
> instantiated from here /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:215:7:
> error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__a < __b’
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:215:7: note: candidates are:
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:207:5: note: template<class _T1,
> class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&,
> const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note: template bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const
> std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note: template<class
> _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const
> std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1049:5: note: template<class
> _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const
> std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1055:5: note: template bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2510:5: note: template<class
> _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const
> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2522:5: note: template<class
> _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2534:5: note: template<class
> _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1290:5: note: template<class
> _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) /usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:586:5: note: template<class ... _TElements,
> class ... _UElements> bool std::operator<(const std::tuple<_TElements
> ...>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing a `typedef` keyword for declaring an alias indicating the iterator category:

```
// Iterator traits - typedefs and types required to be STL compliant
//...
typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
~~~~~~^
```

Without the `typedef`, you are actually declaring a data member.

To avoid such mistakes, you can utilize the [`std::iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/) class template as a base class, instead of defining those aliases on your own:

```
class GridIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag
                                        , typename GridT::Element>
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked! I'll change to using it as a base class. Thanks!

Comment: It worked for std::find, but not std:max_elememt. The last error message is stil there.

Comment: @q-bertsuit the type that iterator points to must be less-than comparable unless you provide a custom comparator to max_element